# I want to compute two quantities of array list by selecting distinct strings

Tags: java, arraylist

I wrote a program

```
public class stock
{
  private int id;
  private string slide;
  private string company;
  private int quantity;
  stock(int id,String slide,String company,int quantity)
  { 
     this.is=id;
     this.slide=slide;
     this.company=company;
     this.quantity=quantity;
```

execution.java

```
Public class Execution
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     ArrayList<stock> s= new ArrayList<stock>();
     s.add(new stock(1,"Buy","her",10);
     s.add(new stock(2,"sell","his",15);
     s.add(new stock(3,"sell","her",13);
     s.add(new stock(4,"buy","his",10);
  }
}
```

this is my code so the input is

```
stockid    slide   company  quantity
1            buy      his     10
2           sell      her     15
3           sell      his     13
4           buy       her     10 
5           buy       her     8
```

the question is I want to execute the sell opposite to buy and vice versa for the same company. That is the quantity given for the company his for sell will be 3 after computing with buy of his itself.
can anyone help me to do this please.

Comment: For a start please format your code

Comment: can you provide an example of the output?

Comment: the out put should be like
Stock Id,    Side,    Company,    Quantity

1,             Buy,         ABC,           10,0,Closed
2,             Sell,         XYZ,           15,0,Closed
3,             Sell,         ABC,           13,3,Open
4,             Buy,         XYZ,            10,0,Closed
5,             Buy,         XYZ,            8,3,Open